# build extjs custom theme

Tags: extjs, sass, extjs6

I created custom theme by [theming system guide](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/guides/core_concepts/theming.html), but don't know how to use new theme in my project. I am not using mvc, mvvm. In my project i connect extjs files in this way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/ext-6.0.0/build/classic/theme-neptune/resources/theme-neptune-all.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/ext-6.0.0/build/ext-all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/ext-6.0.0/build/classic/theme-neptune/theme-neptune.js"></script>
```

How can i add my new theme to project?

After command 'sencha pakcage build' i get an error:
[image: sencha pakcage build error]

Comment: You need to build the theme (`sencha package build`), then include the css and js files.

Comment: Can i use custom theme built in version 6.0.0 with extjs 4.1.1 application ?

Comment: No, you can't. Themes + framework versions have to go together.

Answer (score 2):

You should build your project using sencha command: 
`sencha generate app -ext -classic MyApp MyApp`

Build the theming following the tutorial

change your app.json to point to your custom theme and then run a

`sencha app build`

Answer (score 0):

Add toolkit property to the app.json file.

```
"toolkit": "classic", // or modern
```

Suggestion from this [post](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?299965-Failed-to-resolve-package-ext-6.0.0227&p=1095857&viewfull=1#post1095857).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to create and use your own theme:

1. Create new workspace using specific framework version without project files:

   `sencha -sdk E:\Distr\ExtJS\ext-7.6.0 generate workspace myWorkspace`

   this will create myTheme directory in current root;
2. `chdir ./myWorkspace/ext/`
3. Create new theme (files will appear in./ext/packages/) using theme-triton as primary template:

   `sencha -sdk E:\Distr\ExtJS\ext-7.6.0 generate theme --extend theme-triton myTheme`
4. Edit some things due to sencha guide, for example create ./ext/packages/local/myTheme/sass/var/Component.scss and put *$base-color : #1169de*
   This will change main app color;
5. Build all css: ./ext\packages\myTheme> `sencha package build`
6. Copy ready theme files (also dirs and scss source files, they come together) from ./ext/packages/myTheme/build/ to your project;
7. If you have created you project by your own, without senchacmd, put this css link to index.html:
   `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourPath/myTheme/resources/myTheme-all.css" />`

Some additional information can be found on Sencha guide [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/guide/theming).